# Is there a way to "estimate" an indefinite integral?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, regression

I'm working with empirical data and have estimated the non-linear marginal effects of my independent variable in my dependent variable. Let's call these marginal effects $\frac{dy}{dx}(x)$.

Is there any method by which I can "approximate" the functional form of $y(x)$? I've looked into numerical integration but it is my understanding that this procedure estimates the definite integral.

I tried fitting a polynomial regression on the estimated marginal effects, integrating that and adding the average of my data for $y$ as the constant term. I then used this function to generate the "estimated integral". The result was pretty somewhat noisy so I smoothed the values with LOWESS  (locally weighted scatterplot smoothing).

This works *fine*, but I'm wondering if there's a more sophisticated way of going about things. I'm worried that I'm losing information because the polynomial fit, though pretty good, isn't perfect ($R^2=0.99$) and I don't know how much the choice of polynomial can affect the results. I add graphs of my results (for positive values) below. Thanks in advance!

[image: Estimated marginal effects]

[image: "Estimated" integral]

[image: "Estimated" integral (smoothed)]

Comment: An indefinite integral of $f(x)$ is $\int_0^xf(t)dt $, which can be estimated via approximating a definite integral.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, I can do numerical integration from 0 to x for each value of x? And the resulting values form the "plot" of my indefinite integral?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I’m suggesting.  This setup will give you $0$ at $0$, but you can add an arbitrary constant if you want to shift the graph.

Comment: Hi, can you post this as an answer so I can mark it as the solution? Thanks